# iPhone, is there a maths function like fabs which will make numbers negative values?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've used fabs before which makes passed values positive, but I need a function which will make number negative ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try fabs()*-1?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried fabs()*-1

Answer (score 0):

```
a = (a > 0) ? -a : a;
```